# Duplicate tags: [passport] & [passport.js]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The tags [passport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/passport) & [passport.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/passport.js) are duplicates.

Comment: I had actually just come to ask a question about this. I rejected a couple of tag edits changing `passport` to `passport.js` as I just checked the number of questions and subscribers to the tag and picked the higher.

Comment: However, it's worth noting that `passportjs` is ***already*** mapped to passport. Maybe it should be un-mapped based on Martijn's answer.

Comment: @JamesWebster Yes exactly, see the discussion in the comments of the answer below.

Comment: Yeah I was just reading through those ;)

Comment: I've redirected the [tag:passportjs] synonym to [tag:passport.js] so it will stop feeding into the vague tag.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) **All done**

- The [passport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/passport) tag has effectively been burninated, by moving most questions over to [passport.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/passport.js). The remainder had the tag removed; it was no longer meaningful.
- The `passportjs` synonym has been moved over to [passport.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/passport.js) for us. Thanks [animuson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson)!

*Original answer below the line.*

---

Not quite. There are questions about [Microsoft Passport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353727/what-is-the-difference-between-microsoft-passport-and-openid) or the [Ruby `passport` gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069770/using-fat-secret-api-in-rails-3) or the [too generic *concept* of passports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190333/to-have-multiple-sub-domains-or-multiple-domains) as well. [passport.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/passport.js) questions should not be using [passport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/passport) but it'll take some untangling.

[231 posts mention "passport.js"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpassport%5D+%22passport.js%22+is%3Aq) while using the tag [passport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/passport) only. Similar matches can be made with `passportjs` or the tag [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js) to find more dead-cert `passport.js` questions.

These should be switched to using [passport.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/passport.js), and the tag wiki for [passport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/passport) should be cleaned up, or if not enough questions remain, be burninated.

I've started the process, but it'll take a while; there are over 1000 posts to handle here. Help out if you can! If you do, make sure to also vote to close questions that are off-topic and fix other problems with posts that are on-topic, as you go along

Comment: Sure I can help. Although I'm not completely sure what you've proposed. Firstly, what do you mean by "password" posts? Is that a typo?

Comment: Secondly, I see that there are 1154 questions tagged with "passport", only 78 with "passport.js". Are you suggesting to look up all 1154 "passport" questions and re-tag them with "passport.js"? Wouldn't it be easier to just "merge" the two tags together because I'm sure 99% of the questions tagged with either of those tags just mean "passport.js". I'm also not sure how "merging" would work, I'm guessing you would just change "passport" to "passport.js"? And then we could search for "ruby" in "passport.js" questions and tag them with a new "passport" or better "passport-ruby" tag or something?

Comment: You should only merge if there are no other uses for `passport` as a tag, now and forever. That's because the way to do that is to create a synonym, which means that all future uses of the tag `passport` will automatically be translated to using `passport.js` instead.

Comment: Here  `passport.js` should have been the tag to use *from the start*. This wasn't the case, so now we have a clean-up job of some proportion, yes. There is no other way of preserving the `passport` tag for other non-node.js uses.

Comment: @laggingreflex: all uses of `password` were a typo. I meant `passport` in all cases, sorry about that.

Comment: Alright, I see, so we indeed have to edit all those 1000 questions. You should first edit the wiki for "passport" mentioning it shouldn't be confused with "passport.js"

Comment: @laggingreflex: yes, that's probably a good idea; I'll see to that later today. I've so far handled 40+ posts in between other things, so progress is made.

Comment: I also see that [tag:passport] has been set as synonym for [tag:passportjs] (not [tag:passport.js]). That should also be undone, i.e. [tag:passport] should not be a synonym for [tag:passportjs]. [tag:passport.js] should be a synonym for [tag:passportjs]. (Is undoing actually possible? because if not then there'd be even more confusion. In which case it'd be best to just make them all synonyms.)

Comment: @laggingreflex: we can request that the synonym be removed (or moved to `passport.js`). The *no undo* applies to posts that used `passportjs` as a tag in the past; we cannot revert those back to using that tag. That doesn't matter here.

Comment: Tagged 250+ q's but it seems the system's now throttling me by making me wait upto 30 secs between each edit (severely limiting multiple tabs batch thing I had going on). There really ought to be a better way to do this. Over at reddit they have an automoderator bot that helps with automation, wonder if anyone's written something like that for SO moderation. I think stack API could be used to do this programmatically, I'll look into it.

Comment: I would blacklist passport to make this task easier.

Comment: @Braiam blacklisting is a developer-only option reserved for tags that were burninated but keep resurfacing, and are actively harmful.

Comment: @laggingreflex: once you hit 2k you no longer will be burdening the review queue and editing is effectively unthrottled. We don't want to automate this because this is an excellent opportunity to fix other problems in posts as well, as well as vote to close anything now off topic. Yup, that's a bit of a pain with a tag this size, but we are making great progress here.

Comment: Not true. `installation` is blacklisted in AU and [UL](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/2532) while the tags still exist, but since their number is just too big, to prevent that they keep growing were blacklisted.

Comment: @Braiam: yes, the tag is actively harmful in that it is absolutely useless and should not be used, yet people keep using it. That is not the case here.

Comment: @laggingreflex: down to 473 posts tagged `passport` now; [400 of those are also tagged `node.js`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/passport+node.js), making those almost dead-cert `passport.js` questions.

Comment: [Great success!](http://i.imgur.com/PTXToY9.jpg). [Some posts aren't tagged with node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/passport.js+-node.js) though. I'm just going by [tag:passport]. (sorted by oldest so as to not run into posts that you've gotten to). Also I tried to edit slowly fixing anything and everything else I could find (eg: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15655002/revisions) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9690490/revisions)) but that turned out to be rather extremely slow process. I hope just fixing passport tag blindly as much I can in batch is acceptable enough..

Comment: @laggingreflex: I limit myself to the obvious things; removing *thank you*, etc. I am using targeted searches because so as not to have to pay too much attention to the subject matter; we don't want to retag posts that are **not** about `passport.js` but about some other passport-related subject.

Comment: Lot of those posts which aren't tagged with node.js actually are about passport.js. I have some favourite tags reated to MEAN stack set that highlight anything even remotely related to node.js, even if they aren't tagged with it. And conversely un-highlight those that have nothing to do with node.js, which I don't re-tag.