# Edit rejected for changing restful to RESTful?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6678856

My [main edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281841/duplicate-tags-passport-passport-js) was to change [passport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/passport) to [passport.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/passport.js), which [was accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17503388/revisions), but since I try to do some minor touch-ups as well, this rejection intrigued my curiosity. Was it wrong to change restful to RESTful? I particularly looked it up before changing it too: https://www.google.com/search?q=RESTful

Or could the reason be something else?

Comment: I didn't even realize we *had* a passport tag...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that all edit suggestions are reviewed by individuals, and most likely each edit is being reviewed by a different subset of users. **That makes it all a very subjective process.**

Most likely, the edit was rejected in the context of only itself, not relative to the other edits, under the belief that it just wasn't substantial enough to merit a revision on its own. In general, capitalizing four letters isn't enough to submit an edit suggestion. I'm not going to add commentary as to whether I personally believe that your edit suggestion was valid, because that's not what you asked. You asked why this one was rejected. And the answer was, the reviewers believed it to be too minor.

Comment: In the OP's defense, it wasn't  just capitalizization fix...he edited a tag as well

Comment: @codeMagic Yep, and (since you've broached the topic), I personally would have approved it, given a tag edit.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the top there, another user (who has enough rep to edit without being reviewed) chose

> Mark Rotteveel reviewed this 23 mins ago: Reject and Edit

So he must have thought it was incorrect. It looks to me like it should have just been accepted

To make it more clear and purdy...

[image]

An edit is either accepted or rejected in its entirety. So your tag edit wasn't technically accepted but the reviewer decided that change was fitting so left it in his edit.

Comment: I did see that. As I mentioned in question that my main edit (of tag change) was accepted (rejected and edited to keep just that). I could only guess why he would reject my minor capitalization but keep the tag change because the former one was actually wrong to do. I guess it's just subjective.

Comment: No edit there was really approved. See the update on my answer

Comment: I do understand that my edit (the main one, of tag change) was "kept" but it was technically rejected, no? [This is the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17503388/is-it-possible-to-login-someone-with-their-facebook-account-through-a-restful-se) as of now, it doesn't have my capitalization, and the [revision page](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17503388/revisions) doesn't mention me at all. So in essence the changing of RESTful in particular was rejected. Which leaded me to asking my question.

Comment: @laggingreflex As I said in my answer, he must have thought it was wrong to do. But yes, it is subjective. As I stated, I wouldn't have rejected for that. If you want to look at it that way then yes, the caps part was rejected which rejected the whole thing. Also, I went and looked at the question, review, and edit history before answering ;)